# My webpage loads, then immediately disappears. In chrome dev tools, there are no bad requests.

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Page is: https://www.steveodell.co/kotuprinting.html

This happens on multiple different browsers.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  you have quite a bit of code on that page for us to go through; please consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking for help (which a lot of the time will lead you to figuring out your problem yourself).  thanks!

Comment: Most likely some JavaScript running on your page. No way to tell unless you share some code.

Comment: Chrome provided this error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Your authentication failed. Check your authentication details and try again. For more information on signed authentication, see: http://apiwiki.moz.com/signed-authentication).  In file: jquery.js On line:8625 - GET https://lsapi.seomoz.com/linkscape/url-metrics/www.steveodell.co%2Fkotuprin…e-R3Vlc3Q%3D&Expires=1467114469&Signature=zrJWNe%2Bop4YddOVztIct4xV8bQ8%3D 401

Comment: I'm the ultimate noob. How do I do that? I'm using a bootstrap template, but am only familiar with html css and python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My guess

In https://www.steveodell.co/assets/js/all.js
You have:

```
$("body").imagesLoaded(function(){
    $(".page-loader div").fadeOut();
    $(".page-loader").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Instead of `'.page-loader'` you should fade out `'.loader'`

### Experiment

Go to:

https://www.steveodell.co/kotuprinting.html

Press: Shift+Ctrl+I, select Console and write this at the ">" prompt as a one big line:

```
$(".page-loader, .page-loader div").fadeIn(1000); $(".loader, .loader div").fadeOut(3000);
```

### Possible solution

Find in your HTML where you have the file `assets/js/all.js`
Make a copy of that file somewhere else so you could back it up, just in case.

Find those lines close to the top:

```
// Page loader

$("body").imagesLoaded(function(){
    $(".page-loader div").fadeOut();
    $(".page-loader").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

And change it to:

```
$("body").imagesLoaded(function(){
    $(".loader div").fadeOut();
    $(".loader").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

That is - change `.page-loader` to `.loader` in two places.

### Scrolling

If you enter the Console and enter this code:

```
$('.page-loader, html').css({overflow:'auto'});
```

it seems to be ok. If so, then somewhere in the CSS (or JavaScript) you are setting overflow of `html` to `scrollbar` and overflow of `.page-loader` to `hidden`.

Ok, I think I've found it - in file `assets/css/style.css` you have:

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.page{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try changing it to:

```
html{
    overflow-y: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.page{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

(Change to `auto` in two places.)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Didnt quite fix the problem :/

Comment: @SteveO'Dell Did you paste that line and hit Enter in the console? Maybe try again. It should make your website visible and it would mean that I'm on the right track here and I'll tell you what to do to fix it permanently.

Comment: This removes the loader from the page but its still completely static

Comment: That was also very cool, thanks for that.

Comment: @SteveO'Dell See the update to my answer with "Possible solution". Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay that's better! But, there still isn't any scrolling :/ @rsp

Comment: @SteveO'Dell Ok, you didn't say about scrolling before. I'll take a look.

Comment: was impossible to tell because of the no loading part ha

Comment: @SteveO'Dell Yeah, it's kinda hard to see what's wrong in an invisible page. :) See my latest update - the part Scrolling.

Comment: @SteveO'Dell Did the solution worked for you? Do you accept the answer? (you accept it by clicking the check mark beside the answer)

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, the main element after the body tag in hierarchical form had a `style="display: none"`. This however was not included in the HTML page. Thus it supposes that you included this via jQuery. Please review your code if you applied a `fadeOut()` effect to that element

Comment: I already explained it in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062276/my-webpage-loads-then-immediately-disappears-in-chrome-dev-tools-there-are-no/38062322#38062322) above. In [assets/js/all.js](https://www.steveodell.co/assets/js/all.js) there's `$(".page-loader div").fadeOut();` and `$(".page-loader").delay(200).fadeOut("slow");` which were supposed to fade out the spinner but actually fade out the entire page. The `.page-loader` class name needs to be changed to the real class name of the spinner, which is `.loader`. See my answer for details.