# How to perform or condition in mongo node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I performed or condition with the below code but it is producing duplicates,i think i am wrong at or condition can anyone suggest help please....

```
     function get_profile (id, profiles) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var requests = db.collection('requests');
            var item = { $or: [ {'sent_id':id}, {'recieved_id':id } ] }
                requests.find( item ).toArray((err, resp) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                        return
                    }
                    if (resp) {
                        profiles.push(resp)
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        reject()
                    }
                });
        })
    }

}


exports.getprofiledatalistbyid = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var record = db.collection('profile');
    record.find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return
        }
        if (result) {       
            var profiles_to_get = []
            var profiles = []
            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i]._id;console.log(id)
                var id = id.toString();
                profiles_to_get.push(get_profile(id, profiles))
                // console.log(profiles_to_get)
            }
            Promise.all(profiles_to_get)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log(profiles_to_get)
                  res.send({status: 'success', data: profiles});
                })
        } //end of if loop
        else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }

    })
    //
```

I performed or condition with the below code but it is producing duplicates,i think i am wrong at or condition can anyone suggest help please....

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617451/how-to-perform-or-condition-in-mongo-node/39617597#39617597) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your `profiles` array is not empty when you run the code.

Any reason why you push results to an array and resolve an empty promise instead of using the promise to return the data?

I'm wondering why you use:

```
profiles.push(resp)
resolve()
```

instead of:

```
resolve(resp);
```

You didn't include the code that uses the promise so it's impossible to say anything more. It's just a guess that the array might not be empty to begin with.

To see what you are getting from the database, you can log the data inside of your `if (resp) { ... }` block with something like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
```

### Update

After you added the second part of your code to your question I have even more doubts. Are you getting all of the user profiles from your database and then for each and every one of them you search for profiles that include the id of a profile in its `sent_id` or `recieved_id` field? That seems like a lot of requests to the database.

You can probably do the same with a single request where instead of:

```
{ $or: [ {sent_id: id}, {recieved_id: id } ] }
```

you use:

```
{ $or: [ {sent_id: {$in: ids} }, {recieved_id: {$in: ids} } ] }
```

where `ids` is an array of all IDs that you want to get.

You can probably get the list of IDs with just:

```
var ids = result.map(i => i._id);
```

or something like that inside of your `if (result) { ... }` block.

(By the way, are you sure that the field in your database is called "recieved_id" and not "received_id"?)

Comment: rsp,i am using these function in another,i will edit my code

Comment: @klp I updated my answer after you added more code to the question.

Comment: @rsp That's the problem with [**Chameleon Questions**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @chridam Good point. And you never know when you post an answer only to get the question updated with twice as much code as it was before. My best cameleon question is summarized in [those comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062276/my-webpage-loads-then-immediately-disappears-in-chrome-dev-tools-there-are-no/38062322#comment63563990_38062322).

Comment: with your code i got the error,,,,,,, $in needs an array

Comment: @klp Yes, `$in` needs an array and it should get an array in `ids` - if you did `var ids = result.map(i => i._id);` before as I wrote.